# Not able to start the new service through init.rc in Android

Tags: android

I am modifying `init.rc` in default Android to include the new service that I have created. It's just a script file (`seed_generator.sh`) that I am running once during the init process.

However I am getting an error which states below:

```
type=1400 audit(1462942010.690:5): avc:  denied  { execute_no_trans } for  pid=52 comm="init" path="/system/bin/seed_generator.sh" dev="mtdblock0" ino=436 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

I see that `/system/bin/` has the `seed_generator.sh` and has the right permissions similar to the other services which are started from `init.rc`.

Could someone help me identify what is the problem?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was that SELinux policy for the seed_generator.sh was not defined. After defining this, it started working.

Comment: Can you please add the policy? Your answer isn't complete that way.

Comment: can you advise what exactly to be done, I have same problem

Comment: can you advise what exactly to be done, I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Avc errors are related to SElinux permissions. You can allow or reject the permission from a file called "file_contexts". For example

```
/dev/spidev        u:object_r:spi_device:s0
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to execute these permission very first .

```
chown root:shell seed_generator.sh
chmod 777 seed_generator.sh
chown root:shell init.rc
chmod 750 init.rc
```